# script for create folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Hello I need a script to create folders to a set of images and rename the folders with the image name, in batch or powershell following the example.
I'm not a programmer and do not speak english sorry

before

```
Directory root: 
        AA_1.jpg
        AA_2.jpg
        AA_3.jpg
        BB_0.jpg
        BB_1.jpg
        BB_2.jpg
```

after

```
Directory root:
            subdirectoryAA
              AA_1.jpg
              AA_2.jpg
              AA_3.jpg
            subdirectoryBB
              BB_0.jpg
              BB_1.jpg
              BB_2.jpg
```

Comment: Then maybe you should consider becoming a programmer. Writing a script such as you describe is often among the first things a programmer will learn.

Comment: I am designer just want to automate this process

Comment: We are not a script writing service but a community helping programmers and programming enthusiasts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point: copy the code below, paste in notepad, change the line where `pushd` occurs, save as `anyname.bat` (cf. `29448342.bat` in the output example)

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

        rem Change the current directory to "Directory root"
    pushd "D:\test\29448342"
        rem main loop
    for %%G in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
            rem make destination directory
        md %%G%%G 2>NUL
            rem move files of a given pattern to destination directory
        if exist "%%G%%G*.jpg" move "%%G%%G*.jpg" "%%G%%G\"
    )
        rem Change the current directory back (cf. previous pushd) 
    popd

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat>dir /B /S D:\test\29448342\*.jpg
D:\test\29448342\AA_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\AA_long name 2.jpg
D:\test\29448342\FF_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\FF_long name 2.jpg
D:\test\29448342\GG_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\GG_long name 2.jpg

d:\bat>D:\bat\StackOverflow\29448342.bat
D:\test\29448342\AA_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\AA_long name 2.jpg
        2 file(s) moved.
D:\test\29448342\FF_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\FF_long name 2.jpg
        2 file(s) moved.
D:\test\29448342\GG_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\GG_long name 2.jpg
        2 file(s) moved.

d:\bat>dir /B /S D:\test\29448342\*.jpg
D:\test\29448342\AA\AA_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\AA\AA_long name 2.jpg
D:\test\29448342\FF\FF_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\FF\FF_long name 2.jpg
D:\test\29448342\GG\GG_1.jpg
D:\test\29448342\GG\GG_long name 2.jpg

d:\bat>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- [Script resources for IT professionals](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=VBS&f%5B0%5D.Text=VB%20Script&f%5B1%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=storage&f%5B1%5D.Text=Storage&f%5B2%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B2%5D.Value=Windows%20Shell%20Script&f%5B2%5D.Text=Windows%20Shell%20Script&f%5B3%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B3%5D.Value=PowerShell&f%5B3%5D.Text=PowerShell) (a huge Script repository)

Comment: Very nice of you to help him out.